# Error while build triangle from source: c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'c/triangle.c': No such file or directory

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, msbuild, triangle

I am getting this error while trying to build triangle (The source file can be accessed from here: https://github.com/drufat/triangle) from source:

`
c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'c/triangle.c': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

`
I am using Windows 11, anaconda 3, python 3.9.17
I tried installing different versions of microsoft build tools but I get the same error every time. I even tried on a different machine with different version of anaconda and python, but still im getting the same error. Can somebody help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Did you follow https://rufat.be/triangle/installing.html ?

Comment: The error states `'c/triangle.c': No such file or directory error` is there such a file? What steps have you performed for the installation?

Comment: Just some wild guess... Is `c/triangle.c` part of a longer filename with a path containing space right before the `c/`? Don't do this.

Comment: Yeah i followed this procedure https://rufat.be/triangle/installing.html of building from source but still the same error.  And i cannot see c/triangle.c any of such file

Comment: @Gerhardh im not sure what c/triangle.c is. Also i did not see it anywhere in source code.

Comment: @MohsinBashir HI Mohsin, have you checked Jeremy's answer, does it work for you? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at GitHub, you'll see there is a `c` directory but it looks like this:

`c @ 8b9e104`

This means it is a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). You need to do extra steps to pull it down. If you clone the repo, you need to go into it and then execute the following two commands

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

See the following (done on a Mac but the idea is the same)

```
jeremyp@mymachine dev % git clone https://github.com/drufat/triangle.git
Cloning into 'triangle'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 771, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 771 (delta 11), reused 33 (delta 9), pack-reused 725
Receiving objects: 100% (771/771), 1.83 MiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (362/362), done.
jeremyp@mymachine dev % cd triangle 
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % ls
LICENSE     README.rst  c       doc     pyproject.toml  setup.py    tests       triangle
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % ls c
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % git submodule init
Submodule 'c' (https://github.com/drufat/triangle-c) registered for path 'c'
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % ls c
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % git submodule update
Cloning into '/Users/jeremyp/dev/triangle/c'...
Submodule path 'c': checked out '8b9e1046e5cddab1298d3204f10c93665836cf99'
jeremyp@mymachine triangle % ls c
A.poly      CMakeLists.txt  README      makefile    showme.c    triangle.c  triangle.h  tricall.c
```